# Rails: How to get collection from has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

user belongs_to source
source has_many users

users_controller.rb

```
@users = User.where('u_company = "IBM" ')
```

How can I get the collection of source `@sources` that @users belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
@sources = @users.includes(:source).map(&:source).uniq
```

is what you want

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch souces with a join:

```
@sources = Source.includes(:users).where(users: {id: @users})
```

If you do not need `@users` collection separately, then you can run a single query as follows:

```
@sources = Source.includes(:users).where(users: {u_company: 'IBM'})
```

Comment: Can I user the same thing if users collection like this `@users = User.where('u_company = "IBM" ')`

Comment: @MarcoSong Please check my edit in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

The usual Rails way of structuring this association would be to have a `:source_id` column on the User model so that you could retrieve the associated records for example like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source
end

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

@source = Source.find_by_name('IBM') # assumes that the IBM value is stored in the :name column
# => #<Source id: 123, name: "IBM">

@users = @source.users
# => [#<User id: 456, source_id: 123>, #<User id: 457, source_id: 123>]
# or...
@users = User.where(source_id: @source.id)
```

But if you don't have the default column setup of associating records with id-columns in the database, then you need to specify what columns to use for the call. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source, primary_key: 'name', foreign_key: 'u_company'
end

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, primary_key: 'name', foreign_key: 'u_company'
end
```

The above example once again assumes that the name of the source is stored in a `:name` column.

```
@source = Source.find_by_name('IBM') # assumes that the IBM value is stored in the :name column
# => #<Source id: 123, name: "IBM">

@users = @source.users
# => [#<User id: 456, u_company: "IBM">, #<User id: 457, u_company: "IBM">]
```

If you want more details, then you have to give more information about how your data is structured and how you link them together.